# Google Chrome Dev with strange fonts rendering

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I am using Google Chrome Dev version 19.0.1068.0 on Linux (Debian) and it has a very strange behaviour rendering fonts, examples [Facebook](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43682/facebook_example.png) and [Twitter](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43682/twitter_example.png).

I have the antialias enable and hinting with option full, why this happen?!

cumps ;)

Comment: Your Facebook image just looks like an ugly font; the Twitter image looks like horrible font rendering. What's wrong with the FB image?

Comment: Yah, two images have horrible font rendering, and are so ugly sometimes I cannot read anything because my eyes hurt.